# How can i check the status "scanner" inside my dictionnary

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-json

I have a column roles who is a dictionnary like this:

roles{"admin":false, "scanner":True}

there is my sql request:

```
                select_ticket_query = sql.SQL("""
                SELECT *
                    FROM public.organizer
                    WHERE uid = {uid} 
                    # AND roles.scanner = true
                    # AND FIND_IN_SET(true, roles) 
            """).format(
                uid=sql.Literal(uid),
            )
```

I have tried roles.scanner or roles[scanner] but it doesn't work. I think i should use FIND IN SET but i don't understand it

[image]

This is my roles

Thanks for yours answers

Comment: What is the column type of `roles`?

Comment: it's a dictionnary

Comment: oh fuck, i have seen the image and its a json

Comment: Like you want `roles->"$.scanner"` then to access that json key's value.

Comment: something like that

                SELECT *
                    FROM public.organizer
                    WHERE uid = {uid} 
                    AND roles->"$.scanner" == true

Comment: You might want to read about the [JSON data type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html) and [JSON functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-functions.html) if you're going to use that data type.

Comment: Also read about SQL operators. `==` is not a thing in SQL.

Comment: I'm not sure what `roles->"$.scanner"` is going to output. You might want to toss that in your SELECT clause first and run. Mysql doesn't have a built in boolean literal like `true` or `false` so it might return `1` or `0` or some other representation of that json boolean. In the end, something like `WHERE roles->"$.scanner" = 1` *might* be correct (I'm just guessing though).

Comment: @JNevill, it outputs `true` scalar value as a JSON type. Try it in the mysql command-line client with the `--column-type-info` option.

Comment: @BillKarwin I don't have a mysql server running anywhere presently to test. Just out of curiousity, what would the where predicate look like for this? `roles->"$.scanner" = <true scalar value as a json type>`?

Comment: @JNevill, `roles->'$.scanner' = cast('true' as json)`. Using JSON is seldom elegant or convenient. Also works: `roles->>'$.scanner' = 'true'`. The `->>` does extract and cast to scalar type (if possible).

Comment: @BillKarwin Awesome! Thank you. Filing that tidbit away.